# Adding a block of reviews to the slider

Tags: magento2, review, slider, product-review

Tell me how to make a block of reviews on a product page as a separate slider?

I’ve been looking for some examples for a long time but haven’t found it yet, I hope you can help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your custom theme add:

```
app\design\frontend\CustomVendor\theme-custom\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml
```

In this file we are going to tell Magento to move the reviews block as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="reviews.tab" destination="content" after="product.info.details" />
    </body>
</page>
```

For Magento 2.2.x this command alone will create a 'bug' where the reviews of the product won't show up, but the form will. To fix this issue we are gonna copy the following file:

```
vendor\magento\module-review\view\frontend\web\js\process-review.js
```

And place it in your custom theme in the following path:

```
app\design\frontend\CustomVendor\theme-custom\Magento_Review\web\js\process-review.js
```

In this file go to line and comment those out 40-43 and 44-49 it should look as follows:

```
return function (config) {
    // var reviewTab = $(config.reviewsTabSelector),
    //     requiredReviewTabRole = 'tab';

    // if (reviewTab.attr('role') === requiredReviewTabRole && reviewTab.hasClass('active')) {
        processReviews(config.productReviewUrl);
    // } else {
    //     reviewTab.one('beforeOpen', function () {
    //         processReviews(config.productReviewUrl);
    //     });
    // }

    $(function () {
        $('.product-info-main .reviews-actions a').click(function (event) {
            var acnchor;

            event.preventDefault();
            acnchor = $(this).attr('href').replace(/^.*?(#|$)/, '');
            $('.product.data.items [data-role="content"]').each(function (index) { //eslint-disable-line
                if (this.id == 'reviews') { //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
                    $('.product.data.items').tabs('activate', index);
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $('#' + acnchor).offset().top - 50
                    }, 300);
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
```

We are telling Magento not to check if the reviews are in a tab but just render them either way.

Run Magneto Default Commands:

```
php bin/magento s:up && php bin/magento s:d:c && php bin/magento s:s:d -f && php bin/magento c:c && php bin/magento c:f
```

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: you don’t know how to do it with a slider?

Comment: this removes the sau tab with the form, but you need to move the questions

Comment: You need to just put the slider script or carousel script and you can get it done work as slider.